# How to get my go/src/github.com source files back back?

Tags: go

I accidentally deleted `go/src/github.com` losing all 3rd party package sources.

If I now run `go install ./...` I get a huge list of errors with missing github.com folder locations.

Is there an easy way to `go get` all the missing source packages.

Comment: did you try `go get ./...`?

Comment: ~/go/src/github.com » go get ./..                                                                                             kimmo.hintikka@ie.ibm.com@kimmos-mbp
can't load package: package ./..: non-canonical import path: "./.." should be ".."

Comment: If I use .. go will think in go get "get" is actual package to install and that does nothing

Comment: All packages are still build in go/bin and can be run fine, go path also seems to work I just installed one package to test

Comment: You have something wrong with your imports or file structure. Make sure all imports are correct, and make sure you don't have any symlinks in your GOPATH. The error is referring to `./..` and `..` so it shouldn't be coming from `./...` which is a wildcard that is expanded by the go tools.

Comment: @JimB you are right this behaviour was caused by Python related symlink I had in my .zhsrc file. go get ./... does the trick now. Most packages installed without issues but few give me exit 128 error which I presume are from git command itself. Any tip on that?

Comment: Find the packages that failed to install and see why they failed. If it's git related, look at the git output.